# Creating a package on solaris 10 using pkgmk

Tags: unix, package, solaris-10

I am attempting to create a package using pkgmk on a Solaris10x86. My Makefile.am runs fine until I hit this command:

```
 pkgmk -o -b $(HOME)/solbuild/pkg_solaris
```

Then I get this error:

```
## Building pkgmap from package prototype file.
ERROR in prototype:
> found in search pathinfo
> found in search pathuest
> found in search pathtinstall
> found in search pathtremove
> found in search pathinstall
> found in search pathremove
pkgmk: ERROR: unable to build pkgmap from prototype file
## Packaging was not successful.
```

What does this error mean? I cannot seem to find a clear answer. My files are being found by my prototype, but it is still failing.

Here is my prototype file if it would help:

```
i pkginfo
i request
i postinstall
i postremove
i preinstall
i preremove

d none start/opt/path/directory 0755 root sys
f none start/opt/path/to/file 0400 root sys
f none start/opt/path/to/file2 0744 root sys
d none start/opt/path/directory2 0755 root sys 
f none start/opt/path/to/file3 0755 root sys
f none start/opt/path/to/file4 0744 root sys
d none start/opt/path/to/direcotory3 0755 root sys
e none start/opt/path/to/anotherfile 0744 root sys
e none start/opt/path/to/anotherfile2 0744 root sys
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the problem was is that those files were not using unix line endings which is a big nono. So what I did was used `dos2unix file > tempFile; mv tempFile file` and that fixed it.